# Fix retryWrites=false in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using node v12.16.3, mongodb 4.2 via docker(Official image) and mongodb driver v3.5.8.
When I apply my `insertOne` operation within a transaction I get the following error:

```
This MongoDB deployment does not support retryable writes. Please add retryWrites=false to your connection string.
```

Here is my connection url: `mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017`
Adding retryWrites=false doesn't work (mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017/?retryWrites=false)

Here is how I create mongo client:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017/?retryWrites=false', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```

I intentionally don't specify a default database cause there is no default database, later I used a specific one depending on my business cases:

```
const db = client.db('somedatabae')
```

Any ideas whether I am doing something wrong or there is something else?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a replica set. See https://github.com/p-mongo/mongodb-faq#transaction-support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [D.SM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9540925/d-sm), it really happened that I had to set up a replica set. After that everything worked.